# jQuery function makes page refresh on Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have a `Textarea` and a `Button` that I want to set its value with JQuery when the button clicked.

```
<textarea readonly class="form-control prj-info"></textarea>
```

And my Jquery code:

```
$(".btn-get-prj-info").click(function () {
        if ($('.edt-prj-code').val().length < 7) {
            $("textarea.prj-info").html("ERROR");
        }
        else {
            setTimeout(
                function () {
                    $("textarea.prj-info").html("OK")
                }, 1500);
        }
    })
```

But it has a weird problem! in the else condition when the `Textarea's` text changed, the page's content blinked!!

**This problem is only in Google Chrome.**

I have googled it, but I don't find anything.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle so we can see the problem?

Comment: Likely you have a submit button: `$(".btn-get-prj-info").click(function (e) { e.preventDefault();` or make it a type=button

Comment: @KillerDeath clicking `<>` will create a stack snippet

Comment: Include the button HTML

Comment: @mplungjan, I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: What if you remove SetTimeout?

Comment: @KillerDeath there is no need for a JSFiddle - there is a StackSnippet editor right here if you click the `<>` button in the question/answer editor

Comment: @KillerDeath [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fum5qdhL/) **but on JSFiddle is ok**

Comment: @PedroAntônio I checked it,but has no effect

Comment: @mplungjan thank you but has no effect

Comment: It was a good guess based on the lack of HTML and other code in your question. Also look in the console for errors

Comment: @justin if that fiddle is working, can you make the fiddle look like the actual code that does not work? for example your fiddle is using the onload event. And it is a DIV that is the button in the code that does not work for you? For exampel are you using Angular?

Comment: @mplungjan The console log when the page blinked [screenshot](https://ibb.co/hH3CFw) .The fiddle is exactly like my actual code, of cource the textarea,input and button are in a bootstrap modal. No I dont using Angular

Comment: There is no bootstrap modal code in the JSFiddle and you have not tagged it BootStrap. It is likely that Bootstrap will rewrite your HTML to something completely different from your fiddle

Comment: This is a modal - Does it look and behave like yours? https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/1mvr1x37/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys.
Finally, the problem solved.
For who may have this question:
I used the character `❌` in my code, it makes the page refresh on Chrome that I don't know really why!

```
$("textarea.prj-info").html("❌ title one");
```

Comment: Where did you use it in your code? How can I see this behaviour in your fiddle?

Comment: In the fiddle I summarized my code,because I didn't think "❌" be important. anyway you're right,sorry

Comment: I also cannot reproduce it

Answer (score 0):

As @mplungjan suggests it seems like you're not preventing the button's default action. In HTML, a submit button's action is to reload the page.
You need to pass the event as a parameter to the callback function attached to the button, and prevent it's default action.

Comment: thanks,I have changed the button HTML to `<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-get-prj-info">submit</button>` , but has no effect

Comment: Just trying to help the person(killer death) who says that didn't understand your answer, not trying to get credit from your' s.

Comment: I understood this, I didn't understand how he meant to create a jsfiddle since there was not enough html in the question, that part is solved, he created a fiddle now.

Comment: My bad since I misunderstood your answer. Sorry.

Comment: No problem at all.